# bs4: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' при парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(p):
    url = 'https://www.cian.ru/kupit-kvartiru/'.format(p)
    response = requests.get(url)
    bridge = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    flats = bridge.find_all('article', {'class': '_93444fe79c--container--2pFUD _93444fe79c--cont--1Ddh2'})
    
    info = []
    for flat in flats:
        info.append({
            'General price': flat.find('span', {'class': '_93444fe79c--color_black_100--A_xYw _93444fe79c--lineHeight_28px--3QLml _93444fe79c--fontWeight_bold--t3Ars _93444fe79c--fontSize_22px--3UVPd _93444fe79c--display_block--1eYsq _93444fe79c--text--2_SER'}).text,
            'Adress': flat.find('a', {'class': '_93444fe79c--link--10mjQ'}).text, 
            'Metro': flat.find('a', {'class': '_93444fe79c--link--3ruIo'}).text,
            'Kind of flat': flat.find('span', {'class': '_93444fe79c--color_black_100--A_xYw _93444fe79c--lineHeight_20px--2dV2a _93444fe79c--fontWeight_bold--t3Ars _93444fe79c--fontSize_16px--1mDFP _93444fe79c--display_block--1eYsq _93444fe79c--text--2_SER'}).text, 
            'Time': flat.find('span', {'class': '_93444fe79c--color_gray60_100--3VLtJ _93444fe79c--lineHeight_20px--2dV2a _93444fe79c--fontWeight_normal--2G6_P _93444fe79c--fontSize_14px--10R7l _93444fe79c--display_inline--2gjyY _93444fe79c--text--2_SER'}).text,
            'href': flat.h3.a.get('href')
        })

    return info 


inform = []
for p in range(1, 10):
    inform.extend(get_page(p))
```

Код ошибки следующий:

```
    <ipython-input-41-33245b75d686> in get_page(p)
         17                      'Adress': flat.find('a', {'class': '_93444fe79c--link--10mjQ'}).text,
         18                      'Metro': flat.find('a', {'class': '_93444fe79c--link--3ruIo'}).text,
    ---> 19                      'Kind of flat': flat.find('span', {'class': '_93444fe79c--color_black_100--A_xYw _93444fe79c--lineHeight_20px--2dV2a _93444fe79c--fontWeight_bold--t3Ars _93444fe79c--fontSize_16px--1mDFP _93444fe79c--display_block--1eYsq _93444fe79c--text--2_SER'}).text,
         20                      'Time': flat.find('span', {'class': '_93444fe79c--color_gray60_100--3VLtJ _93444fe79c--lineHeight_20px--2dV2a _93444fe79c--fontWeight_normal--2G6_P _93444fe79c--fontSize_14px--10R7l _93444fe79c--display_inline--2gjyY _93444fe79c--text--2_SER'}).text,
         21                      'href': flat.h3.a.get('href')})
    
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Отчего появляется эта ошибка? Я попробовал сократить число страниц в `range`, не помогло...

Comment: Ну значит `find` ничего не нашёл и вернул `None`

Comment: Те монструозные классы, что у вас указаны в качестве целевых для поиска (в строке с ошибкой это `{'class': '_93444fe79c--color_black_100--A_xYw _93444fe79c--lineHeight_20px--2dV2a _93444fe79c--fontWeight_bold--t3Ars _93444fe79c--fontSize_16px--1mDFP _93444fe79c--display_block--1eYsq _93444fe79c--text--2_SER'}`) - это явно сгенерированные на лету названия. Значит, содержимое страницы динамично и от вызова к вызову названия классов могут меняться. Используйте другие способы поиска содержимого. Например по xpath, css-селекторам, тексту и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Действительно, имена классов на этом ресурсе динамические и меняются от вызова к вызову, поэтому ваш методы `.find()` их не находит и возвращает `None` и, соответственно, не имея воможность применить атрибут `text`, возвращает вам ошибку...

Но не все так уж плохо: даже в этих динамических именах есть одинаковые части для всех карточек (`card` в данном случае), которые можно парсить, используя регулярные выражения и их метод `.compile()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробуем парсить cards:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cian.ru/kupit-kvartiru/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,  'html.parser')

cards = soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile(r'card')})
```

Проверяем количество полученных записей (их 28 на странице):

```
>>> len(cards)
28
```

Внутри карточки даже проще (там есть уникальные `data-mark` в `span`):

```
flats = []
for card in cards:
    title = card.find('span', {'data-mark': 'OfferTitle'})
    subtitle = card.find('span', {'data-mark': 'OfferSubtitle'})
    price = card.find('span', {'data-mark': 'MainPrice'})

    flats.append({
        'title': title.text if title else None,
        'subtitle': subtitle.text if subtitle else None,
        'price': price.text.replace('\xa0₽', '') if price else None,
    })
```

Выводим содержимое списка `flats`:

```
>>> flats
[
    {'title': 'Вид на Москва Сити!', 'subtitle': '2-комн. кв., 52 м², 10/40 этаж', 'price': '15 950 000'}, 
    {'title': 'Квартира с современным ремонтом', 'subtitle': '3-комн. кв., 89,9 м², 21/40 этаж', 'price': '40 000 000'}, 
    {'title': 'Loft River  - Тихая гавань!', 'subtitle': '2-комн. апарт., 66 м², 4/5 этаж', 'price': '22 374 000'}, 

...

    {'title': 'Апартаменты-студия, 54,3 м², 75/96 этаж', 'subtitle': None, 'price': '33 500 000'}, 
    {'title': 'Квартира с просторной террасой', 'subtitle': '6-комн. кв., 393,4 м², 6/7 этаж', 'price': '549 380 110'}, 
    {'title': 'Пентхаус  - 3 этажа - 115,6 м2', 'subtitle': 'Своб. планировка, 115,6 м², 5/5 этаж', 'price': '42 656 400'}
]
```

**UPD** Если хорошо поискать, можно обнаружить внутренний api, который отдает все эти данные (и даже гораздо больше, чем в html) сразу в json:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но это уже совсем другая история ;)
если будет интересно - продолжим в другом вопросе...